# drawImage() with vector drawable, Jetpack Compose Graphics

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-graphics

I was trying to draw a vector drawable (`<vector ...> ... </vector>`) within the `drawScope` as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/overview#draw-image). 
But when I try to use the function given there like
`val imageBitmap = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.my_vector_image)`

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

So, does that mean we can't use `VectorDrawable` with `drawImage`? Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw VectorDrawable inside drawScope via Painter not ImageBitmap.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun DrawSample() {
    val painter: Painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.vd_dashboard_active)

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
        with(painter){
            draw(size = Size(200.dp.toPx(), 200.dp.toPx()))
        }
    }
}
```

If you wish to change position of drawing you can use translate()

```
translate(left = 100f, top = 200f){
    // Your drawing here
}
```